# Calculate distance between more than 2 3D points to determine stoichiometry of protein

Tags: r

Note! This is my first time posting so if anything is not reproducible let me know!

So I have 5 protein subunits. The subunits are called A, B, C, D and E. I also have point data for where the first amino acid of each of these subunits is located in a 3d space. The subunits A, B, C, D and E are supposed to make a ring formation. Is there a way for me to take the 3d point data (shown below) and get R to maybe calculate the distances between these points and return a ring order (aka adding a column to the data frame that says A-C-D-B-E for example)? It doesnt matter which subunit is the first one, all that matters is that I get them out in an order referencing the ring structure.

```
coordinates <- as.data.frame(c(15, -33, -44))
coordinates$B <- c(-13, -55, -8)
coordinates$C <- c(33, -42, -19)
coordinates$D <- c(-18, -53, -1)
coordinates$E <- c(-13, -42, -35)
row.names(coordinates) <- c("x", "y", "z")
colnames(coordinates) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

coordinates <- t(coordinates)

coordinates
```

Just to be super clear, if I plot these points using ggplot2 and gg3D with the following code:

```
devtools::install_github("AckerDWM/gg3D")
library("gg3D")
library("ggplot2")

coordinates <- as.data.frame(coordinates)

qplot(x=0, y=0, z=0, geom="blank") + 
  theme_void() +
  axes_3D()


ggplot(coordinates, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, color=row.names(coordinates))) + 
  theme_void() +
  axes_3D() +
  stat_3D()
```

As you can see in the plot the points sort of form a ring structure, this "order" is what I would want returned, but I have no idea how to do this effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be generalized as a traveling salesman problem. Using the `TSP` package:

```
library(TSP)
(tour <- solve_TSP(ETSP(coordinates)))
#> object of class 'TOUR' 
#> result of method 'arbitrary_insertion+two_opt' for 5 cities
#> tour length: 156.8167
names(tour)
#> [1] "B" "D" "E" "A" "C"
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!